# PreparedStatement cache invalidation when migrating table and after_create hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

There is a bug in RoR 4 when you migrate a table: if you execute a query on this table that has already been executed and is in the prepared statement cache, you get an error.

To get around this issue without having to upgrade to RoR 5, we decided to patch the `ActiveRecord#transaction` method as described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12330#issuecomment-215203613).

Basically the code looks like this:

```
module TransactionRecoverable
  module ClassMethods
    raise "We may no longer need the monkeypatch #{__FILE__}!" if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR > 4

    def transaction(*args)
      begin
        super(*args) do
          yield
        end
      rescue PG::InFailedSqlTransaction => e
        # Raise error to parent transaction if in child transaction.  This prevents issues with dependency errors in a case where you have a transaction that spawns two child transactions, the second depending on the result of the first.  This happens because the rollback_db_transaction rolls back everything under the parent transaction NOT the current transaction.
        raise e if connection.open_transactions > 0

        connection.rollback_db_transaction
        connection.clear_cache!

        super(*args) do
          yield
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class << ActiveRecord::Base
  prepend TransactionRecoverable::ClassMethods
end
```

What it does is when such an error occurs, it triggers a `ROLLBACK` of the current transaction in the DB and then clears the prepared statement cache. Then it re-executes the query, re-building the prepared statement cache for this query with the new table structure.

The issue we are facing now is that if the error occurs during an `after_create` hook, the `ROLLBACK` is triggered and cancels the complete DB transaction (the `create` and the `after_create` SQL statements).

But unfortunately, the only thing that is retried is the code (and therefore the SQL) in the `after_create` hook. So basically there is no crash but my object is not created at all...

Currently I fixed it by replacing the `after_create` hook with an `after_commit` hook but this is not very satisfactory.

Any idea how to fix this ?